# Is this sequence always periodical?

Tags: nt.number-theory, integer-sequences

Is the following sequence always periodical?

[image]

Comment: Unlikely. If $M>10^6$, then it is very rare that a number with $M$ digits is divisible by $M$. So in average you are multiplying more often than dividing, if the starting $n$ is large enough.